# How to make absolute positioned elements overlap their overflow scroll parent

Tags: html, css

I want to make overlap in `absolute` position with grandparent with `overflow:scroll`

```css
.do-scroll{    
  height:  120px;
  overflow-x:hiddem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


    .combo-open section > input {
        display: block;
        margin: 2px auto;
        position: relative;
        width: 98%;
        border: 1px solid #4d7496 !important;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 3px 5px;
    }

.customSelectBox {
    position: relative;
}

.customSelectBox {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
single-select-combo {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);
}

    single-select-combo .contentdropdown.combo-open, multi-select-combo .contentdropdown.combo-open {
        top: 68px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        z-index: 999;
    }

.contentdropdown .dropup, .selected-combo-text {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="do-scroll">
<single-select-combo id="CompanyComboId"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" class="ng-isolate-scope">
<div class="contentdropdown" aria-labelledby="dLabel" id="CompanyComboIdContent" style="position: absolute; display: block; visibility: visible; z-index: 9999;background:red">
    <section class="">
        <span class="selected-combo-text ng-binding" ng-bind="selectedText"></span>
        <span class="dropup"><span class="caret"></span></span>
        <input type="text"  class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched">
        <div class="do-nicescrol" style="height:165px">
           
        </div>
    </section>
</div></single-select-combo>
</div>
```

I see this now

[image: I see this now]

But I want this

[image: I want this]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Its clear, I want to overlap my absolute position overlap from parent div

Comment: Well, not for me it isn't, and your sample code doesn't give a reasonable way to understand it either. Provide e.g. a "before and after" drawing/screendump or something, so we can see the expected output. And note, if someone, who is here to help you, ask you to do something, then do or else you might not get an answer.

Comment: I hope uploaded images be clear for everyone

Comment: That made a difference, still, your live code sample doesn't reproduce that so it will need an update too, as in a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Your question is pretty confusing but let me take a stab at it.

If an item has overflow:hidden as well as position:relative you cannot make a child 
 with position:absolute overlap it's parent.

You can split the position:relative from the parent and put it on a grandparent element instead. This will allow the positioning of the grandchild element to overlap the middle / parent element.

Grandparent has position:relative

```css
.Grandparent {
      background: pink;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 300px;
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
}
.Parent {
      border: 3px dotted teal;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
    /*   position: relative; */
      width: 150px;
}
.Child {
      background: purple;
      height: 75px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 25%;
      left: 25%;
      transform: translate(-75%, -75%);
      width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Grandparent">
      <div class="Parent">Testing testing test 123 ABC do re mi As easy as 123 do re mi testing testing 123 Testing testing test 123 ABC do re mi As easy as 123 do re mi testing testing 123 Testing testing test 123 ABC do re mi As easy as 123 do re mi testing testing 123
            <div class="Child">
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Parent has position:relative

```css
.Grandparent {
      background: pink;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 300px;
  /*   position: relative; */
      width: 300px;
}
.Parent {
      border: 3px dotted teal;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      width: 150px;
}
.Child {
      background: purple;
      height: 75px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 25%;
      left: 25%;
      transform: translate(-75%, -75%);
      width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Grandparent">
      <div class="Parent">Testing testing test 123 ABC do re mi As easy as 123 do re mi testing testing 123 Testing testing test 123 ABC do re mi As easy as 123 do re mi testing testing 123 Testing testing test 123 ABC do re mi As easy as 123 do re mi testing testing 123
            <div class="Child">
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a combo-dropdown like select2.js when I remove `overflow` property from grandparent it work well but when I add `overflow` property my `absolute` position make scroll not overlap

Comment: I think you flipped what I said. position:relative should be on the grandparent. overflow:hidden should be on the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your response I upload 2 images, See them